# Retrieve the count of each record (id) with a condition within CosmosDB

Tags: sql, json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a container within CosmosDB that houses items. *I am needing to find out the count of how many records I have within my container with the conditions of: Source and Date*

This is a sample JSON schema in which each of my records/items holds. Each record has a unique id and acts as a single count.

```
{
"id": "1111111111122222222233333333",
"feedback": {
    "Source": "test"
    "Date": "1980-10-15T00:04:34Z",
    "Ser": "test",
    "Count_Of_Comments": "1",
    "Count_Of_Votes": "1"
}
```

*The container within CosmosDB looks like something like this:*

[image]

*Goal:*
**I wish to return, the numb*er of id records (or the count) based on the Source and the Date.
This is what I have tried (*below),  however this does not seem to work and I am wondering if I am missing something here. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.*

```
 SELECT VALUE COUNT(c.id), c.Source, c.Date
 FROM C
 Where Source == "test", AND Date == "1980-10-15T00:04:34Z"
```

Comment: Are you getting an error trying to run this query? Looks like you have some syntax errors (the comma between the two conditionals, and using `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Yes. Ok let me check this! I also wasn’t sure if COUNT VALUE was the best option to use since I have also seen COUNT(1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David comments,there are some syntax errors.Please try this sql:

```
    SELECT value COUNT(c.id) FROM c Where c.feedback.Source = "test" AND c.feedback.Date = "1980-10-15T00:04:34Z"
```

If you need `Source` and `Date`,you can try this:

```
    SELECT  COUNT(c.id) AS Count,max(c.feedback.Source) as Source,max(c.feedback.Date) as Date
    FROM c
    Where c.feedback.Source = "test" AND c.feedback.Date = "1980-10-15T00:04:34Z"
```

By the way,both `COUNT(c.id)` AND `COUNT(1)` can achieve your goal in your situation.More detail about SQL Query，you can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-getting-started).

Hope this can help you.